# Implementing intercom using angular 10

Tags: angular, angular8, angular10, intercom, intercom.js

I am working on angular 10 application I want to implement intercom in my application. There is nothing in the console and I have installed ng-intercom for it but its not working. No widget appear on my screen there is nothing in iframe as well. Here is my code

App Module

```
IntercomModule.forRoot({
            appId: 'h******8',
            updateOnRouterChange: true
        })
```

Here is my code on home component

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.intercom.boot({
            name: "superadmin,
            email: "super_admin@yopmail.com",
            created_at : '1312182000'
          });
}
```

I am using this code but my page always blank no widget anywhere to click on. Here is the screen shot. Even there is no error on console as well the ping api return ok response.

[home page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzfFO.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are not sending user_hash, in your case you need a user_hash with email and secret, take a look at [this page](https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/183-enable-identity-verification-for-web-and-mobile) for more info on how to get that.

Also, check warnings in the console for intercom warnings.